# How do I rebind the controls in BoI: Rebirth?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

The current control scheme is suboptimal for my play style. Can I rebind the controls to different keys, and if so, how do I do it? I checked in the pause menu, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can rebind the controls. From the main menu, choose **"options"**

[image: Main Menu]

Then choose **"controls"**

[image: Options]

Then choose **"keyboard"**

[image: Controls]

Then you will see this screen

[image: Keyboard controls]

From here, you can move between the options with the arrow keys, select by pressing Space, and choose a different key by pressing that key.

In order to change the controls mid-run, exit the game to auto-save your progress. Then follow the steps as before and from the main menu, choose **"continue"**.

Comment: This goes for mostly every game **ever**!

Comment: "Mostly" is the key word. I didn't think this game had this features, and others didn't either, so when I found it I thought this was a good way to disseminate that information. Plus, this option doesn't appear in the nearly identical in=game options menu, so it's easy to miss.