# How to reactivate controller Binding of Isaac Rebirth

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I just got Rebirth and much to my dismay, mouse controls are no longer supported. So, I decided to try out a controller instead. I'm not too familiar with the controller controls so in order to  pause the game, I unplug the controller in order to prompt a pause screen (keyboard doesn't work with controller active). Now when I plug the controller back in and resume the game, the controller is not active and the game is controlled by the keyboard. How do I make the controller the active device again?

Comment: I believe that the controller unfortunately is far more fragile than a mouse or memory stick when it comes to disconnecting from the computer, so it may be causing the issues when you attempt to reconnect. In order to get it to reconnect, you may have to restart your PC... In future I would "Eject" the controller from the taskbar first.

Comment: The game recognizes the controller (I can become player 2 with it) but Isaac is controlled by the keyboard instead.

Comment: How incredibly intriguing...

Comment: Mouse controls are supported in Rebirth. You need to edit the Options.ini file in Documents/My Games/Binding of Isaac Rebirth and set MouseControl=0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest update, you can go to your Isaac folder, look for `options.ini` and open it with a text-editor of your choice. set *PauseOnFocusLost* to 1 (`PauseOnFocusLost = 1`).

Now you can simply use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other shortcut which changes the window focus and the game will lose focus, triggering a pause.

This way you don't need to unplug the controller. Also most coontrollers have a *pause-key* in Rebirth. You can resume the game using the controller with the key for *options-back* (the same you use to go back one level in menus).

Answer (score 0):

Unplug a controller while playing is not a good idea, because not every game lets you to change the type of controller "in game".
If your only problem is the Pause button, you'd better check or change your controls from the **Main Menu** options, as asked before [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190816/87579).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just exited the game and then went back in and now it works. Now I know the controls so I won't do that again.